# Brake imbalance

Tags: brakes

I had my car fixed after a collision to the front drivers side, onto the wheel. Car was fixed under insurance and has been taken for an MOT and failed on front brake imbalance across an axle.

Front brakes are 18 months old with 20k miles on them, front wheels 6months old.

Could this failure be caused by the crash or just wear and tear?

I've not spoken to garage yet to find out the finer details.

Comment: was only the brakes on one side changed if this is the case they have made an error,brake parts are sold in pairs so they have not saved any money by doing so.

Comment: I changed both side 18 months ago. Garage who did the repair only changed the body damage I presume. I have to go in tomorrow to find out what the heck is going on.

Comment: Bleed the brakes

Comment: Did you get the detailed brake test report from the MOT? That has a lot of useful information, not just total braking force, but also whether the brakes are binding, which wheel(s) were locked by the brakes, and if the braking force fluctuates as the wheels rotate.

Comment: Have you checked to see if a piston or pistons are seized in the calipers?